# how i can create a page that works like stackoverflow

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

i want to know how did these pages work!
like this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

there is no extension in end of the address!

is this a way to call webmethods directly?!
i wrote this page , but i think its not right!

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string name= Request.QueryString["name"];
           if (Request.PathInfo == "/SayHi")Response.Write( SayHi(name));
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string SayHi(string name)
        {
            return "Hi " + name;
        }

        //[WebMethod]
        //public static string SayHi()
        //{
        //    return "Hi ";
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ASP.NET`, you can use [`ASP.NET Routing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx), which will allow you to separately configure what the URLs should look like.

You can use it both for [regular WebForms apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application) and with the newer [ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_routes_to_an_mvc_application).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).  It's the framework that runs the Stack Overflow site per [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).  MVC uses the [routing engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to allow urls without a trailing ".aspx".

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC as its core web technology and you are right there are no extensions, because there is a routing engine that handles requests.

In your example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

This would equate to the StackOverflow site invoking a controller named `ask` and displaying its default view, based upon the rules setup for the routing engine.

Read [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) for more information on how ASP.NET MVC routing works.

UPDATE:

For more information on what software and hardware the StackOverflow site was originally built on, then read [What Was Stack Overflow Built With?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/). This is generally still correct, although some of the hardware and amount of each may have changed with an increased user base.

Comment: thank you so much friends! now , can you tell how i can handle route in jquery?! i mean how i can use parameters